# can json.loads() take function reslut(string) as input?

Tags: python, json

As I know json.loads() take string as input, so I don't know why below code doesn't work.

```
import json
fileref = open("olympics.txt", "r").readline()  # the output is str
print(fileref)
print(type(fileref))
d = json.loads(fileref)
```

Error:

```
ExternalError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0 on line 8
```

Thank you!

Comment: What was the result of `print(fileref)` - we'll need the source string to answer this. It says there is a problem on line 8, but it came from readline, which is puzzling to say the least.

Comment: We would like to see that ```olympics.txt``` file. It looks like you don't have correct JSON file in it.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `fileref` is not a syntactically valid JSON string. Unless you know the first line of the file is supposed to be a JSON object then I'm assuming the entire file is a JSON object (which is common). You can use the json.load function to read in a file https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html.

Or you could store the file into a string and then use loads like

```
content = ""
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
     for line in f:
         content += line
json.loads(content)
```

EDIT: I do not know you're file structure, I am just assuming that its a JSON file (i.e its all JSON). If that is the case then what I mentioned would be accurate. Otherwise the error you are seeing is because the string being parsed is not valid JSON.